# Get previous version of entity in Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I have an entity loaded by Hibernate (via `EntityManager`):

```
User u = em.load(User.class, id)
```

This class is audited by Hibernate Envers. How can I load the previous version of a User entity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe this then (from [AuditReader](http://www.jboss.org/files/envers/api-beta/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html) docs)

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
User user_rev1 = reader.find(User.class, user.getId(), 1);

List<Number> revNumbers = reader.getRevisions(User.class, user_rev1);
User user_previous = reader.find(User.class, user_rev1.getId(),
  revNumbers.get(revNumbers.size()-1));
```

(I'm very new to this, not sure if I have all the syntax right, maybe the size()-1 should be size()-2?)

Comment: It does need to be `size()-2` to get the second-to-last revision

Comment: Why there is `user_rev1` at all? `reader.getRevisions` accepts primaryKey as second argument. Not entity. So all you need is
    `AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    List<Number> revNumbers = reader.getRevisions(User.class, user.getId());
    User user_previous = reader.find(User.class, user.getId(),
  revNumbers.get(revNumbers.size()-1));`

Answer (score 25):

Here's another version that finds the previous revision relative to a "current" revision number, so it can be used even if the entity you're looking at isn't the latest revision. It also handles the case where there *isn't* a prior revision. (`em` is assumed to be a previously-populated EntityManager)

```
public static User getPreviousVersion(User user, int current_rev) {
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);

    Number prior_revision = (Number) reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(User.class, false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().max())
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(user.getId()))
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().lt(current_rev))
    .getSingleResult();

    if (prior_revision != null)
        return (User) reader.find(User.class, user.getId(), prior_revision);
    else
        return null
}
```

This can be generalized to:

```
public static T getPreviousVersion(T entity, int current_rev) {
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(JPA.em());

    Number prior_revision = (Number) reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(entity.getClass(), false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().max())
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(((Model) entity).id))
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().lt(current_rev))
    .getSingleResult();

    if (prior_revision != null)
        return (T) reader.find(entity.getClass(), ((Model) entity).id, prior_revision);
    else
        return null
}
```

The only tricky bit with this generalization is getting the entity's id. Because I'm using the Play! framework, I can exploit the fact that all entities are Models and use `((Model) entity).id` to get the id, but you'll have to adjust this to suit your environment.

Comment: Won't `forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz,false,true)` return an `Objec[]` with instance, revision info and revisionType? How can it be typecasted to `Number`?

Comment: the addProjection changes this to return the revision number, is there a way to have it return the entity directly? (Instead of running the find again afterwards)

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be this:

```
final AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( entityManagerOrSession );

// This could probably be declared as Long instead of Object
final Object pk = userCurrent.getId();

final List<Number> userRevisions = reader.getRevisions( User.class, pk );

final int revisionCount = userRevision.size();

final Number previousRevision = userRevisions.get( revisionCount - 2 );

final User userPrevious = reader.find( User.class, pk, previousRevision );
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the excellent approach of @brad-mace,  I have made the following changes:

- You should pass in your EntityClass and Id instead of hardcoding and assuming the Model.
- Don't hardcode your EntityManager.
- There is no point setting selectDeleted, because a deleted record can never be returned as the previous revision.
- Calling get single result with throw and exception if no results or more than 1 result is found, so either call resultlist or catch the exception (this solution calls getResultList with maxResults = 1)
- Get the revision, type, and entity in one transaction (remove the projection, use orderBy and maxResults, and query for the Object[3] )

So here's another solution:

```
public static <T> T getPreviousRevision(EntityManager entityManager, Class<T> entityClass, Object entityId, int currentRev) {
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    List<Object[]> priorRevisions = (List<Object[]>) reader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(entityClass, false, false)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId))
            .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().lt(currentRev))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getResultList();

    if (priorRevisions.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    // The list contains a single Object[] with entity, revinfo, and type 
    return (T) priorRevision.get(0)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
User user_rev1 = reader.find(User.class, user.getId(), 1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works for my, I want to get the previous version, your example get a mandatory version (in this case, the version number 1).