# Return Hibernate envers Audit revision with modified flags

Tags: java, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers in my app to track changes in all fields of my entities. 
I'm using @Audited(withModifiedFlag=true) annotation to do it.

The records are been correcty recorded at database and the _mod fields correctly indicate the changed fields.

I want to get a particular revision from some entity and the information of what fields have been changed. I'm using the follow method to do it:

```
        List<Object[]> results = reader.createQuery()  
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(this.getDao().getClazz(), false, true)  
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))  
            .getResultList();
```

This method returns an list of an object array with my entity as first element.

The problem is that the returned entity doesn't have any information about the changed fields. **So, my question is:** how to get the information about the changed fields?

Comment: You could try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577363/getting-the-old-value-and-new-value-between-two-revisions-with-hibernate-envers with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793674/get-previous-version-of-entity-in-hibernate-envers

Comment: These guys want exactly the same thing than I. Looks like envers do not give it by default. I will try to implement that solution, recovering the previous object and setting by myself the diff. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is a bit old now but I was trying to do this and didn't really find any answers.

There doesn't seem to be a *nice* way to achieve this, but here is how I went about it.

Firstly you need to use projections, which no longer gives you a nice entity model already mapped for you. You'll still get back an array of Objects but each object in the array corresponds to each projection that you added (in order).

```
final List<Object[]> resultList = reader.createQuery()  
        .forRevisionsOfEntity(this.getDao().getClazz(), false, true)
        // if you want revision properties like revision number/type etc
        .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber())
        // for your normal entity properties
        .addProjection(AuditEntity.id())
        .addProjection(AuditEntity.property("title")) // for each of your entity's properties
        // for the modification properties
        .addProjection(new AuditProperty<Object>(new ModifiedFlagPropertyName(new EntityPropertyName("title"))))
        .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
        .getResultList();
```

You then need to map each result manually. This part is up to you, but I'm use a separate class as a revision model as it contains extra data to the normal entity data. If you wanted you could probably achieve this with @Transient properties on your entity class though.

```
final List<MyEntityRevision> results = resultList.stream().map(this::transformRevisionResult)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


private MyEntityRevision transformRevisionResult(Object[] revisionObjects) {
    final MyEntityRevision rev = new MyEntityRevision();
    rev.setRevisionNumber((Integer) revisionObjects[0]);
    rev.setId((Long) revisionObjects[1]);
    rev.setTitle((String) revisionObjects[2]);
    rev.setTitleModified((Boolean) revisionObjects[3]);
    return rev;
}
```